# Haskell print and use a value from a monad

Tags: haskell

So, what I'm trying to do is print two values before I use them. Here's two ways which work perfectly, but I feel like there are other ways I could do it. I know the suggested way to do it is likely the do block since its laid out and is least complicated, but why not see how else?

```
-- 1
main = do
    a <- m1
    b <- m2
    print a
    print b
    print $ f a b

-- 2
p x = print x >> return x

main = print =<< liftM2 f (p =<< m1) (p =<< m2)
```

I've also tried these, but they have their problems I'm not quite able to figure out and there never seems to be the right things to chain together.

```
main = print =<< foldl1 f . mapM p =<< sequence [m1, m2]
main = print =<< on f p m1 m2
main = print . curry (on f) =<< (uncurry (join (***)) p) m1 m2
```

I think that `on` from Data.Function is pretty close to what I want to do, but I don't know how to pipe in two monadic values. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: The first question is a bit broad: How can I rewrite the first do block? My other question is how can I extract two values from monads into a function that takes two values?
If there was a function that did something like `(m a, m a) -> m (a, a)` then I think could do `curry (on f p) =<< thatfunction (m1, m2)`, but there could be another way.

Comment: If this is purely for debugging purposes, then [`traceShowId`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId) from `Debug.Trace` might help.

Comment: @AlexisKing, if they need a monadic context for something else, that seems like overkill, but a relative of a good solution.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexisKing That seems like a great solution, but this isn't only for debugging. It'll be helpful in the future though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want this:

```
main = (liftM2 f `on` (>>= p)) m1 m2 >>= print
       where f = (++)
             p x = print x >> return x
             m1 = getLine
             m2 = getLine
```

- `liftM2 f` creates a version of `f` whose "arguments" are both monadic values.
- `on` creates a function that passes both "arguments" through `(>>= p)` before passing them on to `liftM2 f`.
- The final result is then bound to `print`.

As a result, this example

1. Waits for a line to be entered, then prints that line
2. Waits for another line to be entered, then prints *that* line
3. Concatenates the two lines then prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some Applicative-style combinators that perform printing if you wanted to make things a little bit shorter:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO(..))

(<*&>) :: (MonadIO m, Show a) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
mf <*&> mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  liftIO $ print x
  return $ f x

(<$&>) :: (MonadIO m, Show a) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
f <$&> mx = pure f <*&> mx
```

(The names probably leave something to be desired, but I’ll leave that up to you.)

With these operators, you could write your original example like this:

```
main = print $ f <$&> m1 <*&> m2
```

Whether or not you think this is clearer is up to you (and probably up to how frequently you use this pattern).